# OutputCache with Redis working on Localhost but not Azure WebApp

Tags: c#, azure, redis, outputcache

I'm writing a standard MVC 5 application, and set OutputCache tag on the controllers, also installed StackExange.Redis and RedisOutputCache. Configured the web.config accordingly.

The cache works perfectly when I Run this in localhost, however once deployed into an Azure WebApp, the cache doesn't work as I See the changes coming through. Also when debugging the App remotely, i see the breakpoint hits in the controller view action.

I have been looking for days for a solution, but I could not find any answer, not even something similar. I already raised a ticket on Azure Support.

So my questions is, is there something that could make the Azure WebApp behave differently from the local solution? 
How could I debug Outputcache to check why it doesn't hit the cached version?

Additional info: I see in the Redis Cli the that Outputcache is storing the cached version, it's just it doesn't return it.

Thanks

Comment: On stackoverflow "Show me your code" attitude. Can you extract a piece of code behaving different on local and Azure?

Comment: Please post your web.config. *Mask the sensitive information.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found the issue.

I was using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name` in the `VaryByCustomString()` function in `global.asax` to create a culture based cached version.

However, once deployed to Azure WebApp this culture appears to be not set, so the check fails and the `OutputCache` thinks there isn't any version in Redis.